# how to repopulate form during an edit action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the problem.i need to have the values of the form while updating.It is cumbersome to fill them again in a form if for some reason the form isnt submitted.i have tried using instance variable .it works properly with other controllers but isnt repopulating the admin form.please help

Answer (score 0):

Create the partial of the form '_form_partial.html.erb'. In the form pass the object

```
<%= form_for your_object  do |f| %>
```

Now in your controller add following methods

```
def new
  @object = YourModelClass.new
end

def edit
  @object = YourModelClass.find(params[:id])
end
```

Now in new.html.erb and edit.html.erb render your partial as

```
<%= render partial: 'path_to_your_partial' , locals: { object: @object } %>
```

It will automatically populate the form for you.